# Invalid hook call in getServerSideProps (Nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('repoData', () =>
    fetch(
      'https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query'
    ).then((res) => res.json())
  )
  console.log({ data })

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  }
```

Although there are many questions related to react invalid hook call in stackoverflow but still none of them able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use hooks in `getServerSideProps`. Instead, you can fetch the data and pass it to the `useQuery` hook in your component as initial data as explained in the [SSR docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-initialdata):

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const posts = await getPosts()
  return { props: { posts } }
}

function Posts(props) {
  const { data } = useQuery('posts', getPosts, { initialData: props.posts })

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the official docs this is the correct way to do it.

```
const getPosts = () =>
  fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query').then((res) =>
    res.json()
  )
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const queryCache = new QueryCache()

  await queryCache.prefetchQuery('posts', getPosts)

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryCache),
    },
  }
}
```

Home Component

```
 const { data } = useQuery('posts', getPosts)
```

Comment: There is no use of a hook in your solution. I believe the useQuery in the OP would refer to the apollo hook which cannot be used in getServerSideProps. For the record: It's probably worth noting that a **very** similar question was asked and answered [in nextjs on github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17613).

Answer (score -4):

Is `getServerSideProps` a hook? If so, you must call it `useServerSideProps`.

(EDIT after @Patrick_Roberts comment, saying it is not a hook but a special function)

Then you cannot call `useQuery` (anything starting with `use` is considered a hook) in it… If `useQuery` is not a hook, then you should rename it. If it is an external function which cannot be renamed, simply disable the linter error for this line.

See https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: It's not a hook, it's a special function you can export in Next.js