# Can I use UseState with Server-Side-Rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Can you use useState (and other react hooks?) with Server Side Rendering? Every time I am trying to run the code below I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null.

However, when I comment out the getServerSideProps function at the very bottom I have no problem running the code as intended. So my questions is can useState be used with Server Side Rendering in Nextjs? If the answer is yes, then where am I going wrong in the code below?

```
 import React from "react";
    import { useRouter } from "next/router";
    import useSelectedGenreInfoExtractor from "../../hooks/useSelectedGenreInfoExtractor";
    import { useState } from "react";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar";
    import useFetchTrendingCatagory from "../../hooks/useFetchTrendingCatagory";
    import useFetchTopRatedCatagory from "../../hooks/useFetchTopRatedCatagory";
    import useFetchMovieGenreResults from "../../hooks/useFetchMovieGenreResults";
    import Moviegenreresults from "../../components/Moviegenreresults";
    
export default function genre(props) {
      const [myresultsfromhook, setMyresultsfromhook] = useState();
      const [myreturnedmovies, setMyreturnedmovies] = useState();
    
      const router = useRouter();
      const { genre } = router.query;
    
      if (genre == "Trending") {
        let mymovies = useFetchTrendingCatagory();
        console.log("This is a log of my props", props);
    
        return (
          <div>
            {/* <Navbar /> */}
            <div>{genre}</div>
            <Moviegenreresults movies={mymovies} />
          </div>
        );
      } else if (genre == "Top Rated") {
        let mymovies = useFetchTopRatedCatagory();
    
        return (
          <div>
            {/* <Navbar /> */}
            <div>{genre}</div>
            <Moviegenreresults movies={mymovies} />
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        let mymovies = useFetchMovieGenreResults(genre);
    
        return (
          <div>
            {/* <Navbar /> */}
            <div>{genre}</div>
            <Moviegenreresults movies={mymovies} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      if (context.params.genre == "Trending") {
        let mymovies = useFetchTrendingCatagory();
        return {
          props: {
            results: mymovies.results,
          },
        };
      } else if (context.params.genr == "Top Rated") {
        let mymovies = useFetchTopRatedCatagory();
        return {
          props: {
            results: mymovies.results,
          },
        };
      } else {
        let mymovies = useFetchMovieGenreResults(genre);
        return {
          props: {
            results: mymovies.results,
          },
        };
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can't use hooks in `getServerSideProps`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64202834/invalid-hook-call-in-getserversideprops-nextjs.

Answer (score 4):

`useState` should be inside the component, it is a React hook. serverside functions are independent of React components.

I think the issue is the name of the component should be with capital letter:

```
 // not genre
 export default function Genre(props)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think fundamentally the problem is the way you are using getServerSideProps.

Even thought the answer is you can not use useState inside getServerSideProps because this function run in the server, it is important to understand what getServerSideProps does and when, I think you can find very clear explanation about that in next docs.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Inside getServerSideProps use axios or the fetch api to get your data and pass it to the props.

I am not 100% sure but I thinnk inn your case you can also use Promise.all() to get the data from those three api calls.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: So just to be clear, are you saying I cannot use useState on the same page I use getServerSideProps on? Or are you saying I can not use useState INSIDE the getServerSideProps functions (because I did not in the example).  Also, is it possible that instead of using axios or fetch inside getServerSideProps, that I use custom Hooks? I think this should be possible as I don't see a difference between using custom hooks or writing my functions directly inside the getServerSideProps function.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were using useState inside useFetchMovieGenreResults. Because I can not see you are using  myresultsfromhook, myreturnedmovies anywhere else. Also, what are you returning from useFetchMovieGenreResults and why are you using it in getServerSideProps and inside the components aswell? Plus I don't see you using your props any where on the template.

Comment: @Iwanttoknow _"Also, is it possible that instead of using axios or fetch inside getServerSideProps, that I use custom Hooks?"_ - That is not possible because hooks need React and only work in function components and/or other React hooks. `getServerSideProps` is just a special function that runs on the server (no React available).

Comment: @Iwanttoknow _"are you saying I can not use useState INSIDE the getServerSideProps functions (because I did not in the example)"_ - You may not be using `useState` _directly_ in `getServerSideProps` but my guess is that the custom hooks you call in there have `useState`s somewhere inside them. Hence why your error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue, but the solution ended up different so posting it here in case someone benefits in future.

Basically, one of the causes for `TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null` can be React loaded multiple times and because of that unable to track properly if the hook is within the component.

There is a lot more details [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) and [here](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) and the root cause could be very different but likely to do with how the code is bundled. In my specific case, I had a separate folder for SSR code and shared code, and both of these had separate `react` and `react-dom` installed in their `package.json`. Removing the `react` and `react-dom` from the SSR specific folder and just reusing the shared one fixed the issue